# Codeigniter working on one server but not on another server

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, codeigniter-url

I have developed a web application using codeigniter. In my localhost it works properly. But while i am hosting it to the live server (shared server) it's not working.
I am getting the home page while calling the main URL on live server, but any URL through controller is not working

When calling the URL "http://my_domain.in/pages/second_page" getting the following error

`The requested URL /my_domain.in/my_domain.in/index.php/pages/second_page was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache Server at my_domain.in Port 80`

I noticed on the error string URL that my domain name is repeating but on actual URL it is not like that and index.php also found. So i have changed .htaccess codes so many times to solve this issue. That time the URL on Error message is changing but no successful result occurred.

At last i have hosted it on my friend's server. that time it works properly as like my localhost. Can you please tell me what will be the problem of my server? Is there anything to enable or disable while using codeigniter on that server? The codeigniter framework is never used in this server.

Comment: it looks like your live server has some custom mod_rewrite configuration, which conflicts with your htaccess. You should ask your hosting administrator for assistance

Answer (score 0):

For getting better answer you need to provide the hosting provider name. You can try with the following .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1
```

Comment: It is also not working. Think the problem is not of the htaccess. I think it is of server property. My hosting provider is godaddy.

Comment: But sorry yaar..it is not working. Please let me to know where ever  we want to put our .htaccess file? I put only in main directory near index.php. is it the correct methord? Is there anything to do on server side?

Answer (score 0):

It looks youare hiding the index.php but the error is mentioning it
 ==> /my_domain.in/my_domain.in/**index.php**/pages/second_page was not found

Did you remove it in the config page too?
\config\config.php

make sure $config['index_page'] = '';
and add the  .htaccess file with these lines

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I had this problem when testing on Windows and Linux machines and adjusted the config.php like this.

```
    if (file_exists(FCPATH.'.htaccess')) {
     $config['index_page'] = '';
    }
    else {
     $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
    }
```

First teste without the .htacsess file
If all went well, place the .htaccess file in the root and try again.

If you still get this error, look at the links you have coded and see if the index.php is mentioned in it.